# change loses bind reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have a link that uses the ID to grab specific content from an external file (works, no problems here).  I then change the ID of the link so that a new ID so that new info can be gotten the from the external file but the same info is always shown.  So, I'm looking for some help in figuring out why the new info isn't being loaded but the old instead.

Here is the code for setting the new ID value.  It resides in a completely separate section of the code.  It then calls the function *fncSetupInfoWindow()* and it creates the bindings.  *.windowInfo* is a class set on specific elements.

```
$('#pickedCenterProgram a').text(newProgram[0]).parent().slideDown().attr('id', newVal).attr('title', newProgram);
fncSetupInfoWindow();


function fncSetupInfoWindow() {
$('.windowInfo').unbind('mouseover mouseout').each(function () {
    var obj = $(this), position = [], contentID = globalObjects.emptyString, title = obj.attr('title'), contentID = obj.attr('id').toLowerCase();
    obj.bind({
        mouseover: function (e) {
            position = fncGetPositionArray(e.pageX, e.pageY);
            fncLoadStatusInfo(position[0], position[1], contentID, title);
        },
        mouseout: function () {
            $('#modInfoWindow').closeModal();
        }
    });
});
```

}

Here is the code for loading the info

```
function fncLoadStatusInfo(x, y, programName, title) {
initLoader.className = 'txt-c'; //create loader
initLoader.iconClass = 'alignVert-b';
$('#modInfoWindow').createModalWindow({ isModal: false, left: x, top: y, ignorePosition: false, title: title, width: 250, hideCloseIcon: true, autoOpen: true }).html(initLoader.createLoader());
$('#modInfoWindow').load('../pages/infoFile.htm ' + '#' + programName);
return false;
```

}

Everything works, well almost, except that the newly assigned ID is not being used but the original for when the page is created.  I've tried numerous things as well as even destroying the modal (aka dialog) window all with the same results.

thanks ^.^

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide test case on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the `id` *at the time it was bound* (inside the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)), rather than *at the time of the event* (inside the event handler).  You can do it at the time of the event *and* simplify things overall like this:

```
function fncSetupInfoWindow() {
  $('.windowInfo').bind({
      mouseover: function (e) {
          var pos = fncGetPositionArray(e.pageX, e.pageY);
          fncLoadStatusInfo(pos[0], pos[1], this.id.toLowerCase(), this.title);
      },
      mouseout: function () {
          $('#modInfoWindow').closeModal();
      }
  });
}
```

Or even simpler (*probably* what you want) using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
function fncSetupInfoWindow() {
  $('.windowInfo').hover(function (e) {
    var pos = fncGetPositionArray(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    fncLoadStatusInfo(pos[0], pos[1], this.id.toLowerCase(), this.title);
  }, function () {
    $('#modInfoWindow').closeModal();
  });
}
```

Comment: Using the hover is a much better option.  Unfortunately, this still didn't solve the problem.   The same thing is still happening.

Comment: @user546656 - what issues are you still seeing?

Comment: Turns out that the solution was to pass the new ID to the function instead of trying to grab it.  The reason for this was only because the function was running before the other info completely ran.